# Google Maps API v3 UNIQUE marker JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to have a unique marker on a simple javascript web API, no jQuery.

I first tried to delete the previous marker every time I click on the map, with

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

just before creating the new one, but it blocks the new one, nothing appears on the screen.

I can easily delete the markers with a button or other event, but is there a way to do it automatically, and have only one marker on the map (with draggable: true to move it, maybe dblClick to delete it) ?

Marker creation triggered by usual

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {...

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...
```

The interface is used to define a single location so I don't want more than one marker on the screen; coordinates are then saved in a database.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the marker by using the `var`-keyword the variable will not be accessible later, the call of `setMap` fails(and stops the further script-execution) because of the undefined variable.

Example using a single marker(marker will be stored as property of the map):

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
      //closure for the map
      var that=this;
      //only create a single marker
      if(!this.marker){
         var input = document.getElementById("location_name");
         this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({draggable:true,title:input.value});
         google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker,'dblclick',function(){
            this.setMap(null);
         });
         //update title
         google.maps.event
          .addDomListener(input,
                          'change',
                          function(){ 
                            that.marker.setTitle(this.value);
                          }
                         );
      }
      //update position
      this.marker.setOptions({map      : this,
                              position : event.latLng
                             });
    });
```

Comment: It works perfectly now ! Thanks. Only problem is that I used a function to change the document.getElementById("location_name").onchange = function() { marker.title = document.getElementById("location_name").value; } and now it's not updated anymore when I edit the form field id="location_name"... also a "scope" problem ?

Comment: The marker will now be accessible via `map.marker`. However, it's not clear if `map` is global accessible in your implementation, you may add the `change`-listener when you create the marker(without any scope-issues). See the modified code above.

Comment: Thanks ! so we have "map.marker", "this.marker", "that.marker" ! I'd really need to study js more. Funny thing is that the dblClick, drag value update and marker.title change only work after the 2nd click on the map, the first click creates the marker, but these functions are activated only after I click a 2nd time. I remember seeing that in javascript (not google maps related) already.

Comment: `map.marker`, `this.marker` and `that.marker` are all the same object, it depends on the scope how you may access the ``map`-object. When you have stored the map as a global variable you may use only `map.marker`. Related to the 2nd click:  the `dbclick` is immediately "activated", but of course dblclick requires 2 clicks.

Comment: The issue with the title is the following: the change-event of an input fires when you change the value and the input loses the focus(e.g. when you click on the map, but you could also click somewhere else). You may use the `input`-event instead. There is nothing inside my code which observes the marker-drag, so I can't tell you anything without seeing your code.

Comment: Yes I have a slighty different structure, and I had to add   `this.marker.setMap(map);`   just before closing the `if(!this.marker){...}`   that allows everything to fire immediately (I have "dblclick" and "dragend" inside the "click" listener {}, and other functions outside with `document.getElementById("...").onchange` functions). Thanks for your help, everything runs fine now, until I add some more functions !